# private[this] vs private

Tags: scala

In Scala I see such feature as object-private variable. From my not very rich Java background I learnt to close everything (make it private) and open (provide accessors) if necessary. Scala introduces even more strict access modifier. Should I always use it by default? Or should I use it only in some specific cases where I need to explicitly restrict changing field value even for objects of the same class? In other words how should I choose between

```
class Dummy {
    private var name = "default name"
}

class Dummy {
    private[this] var name = "default name"
}
```

The second is more strict and I like it but should I always use it or only if I have a strong reason?

EDITED: As I see [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_access_modifiers.htm) `private[this]` is just some subcase and instead of `this` I can use other modifiers: "package, class or singleton object". So I'll leave it for some special case.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/twolfe18/5767545

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I don't think it matters too much, since any changes will only touch one class either way. So the most important reason to prefer `private` over `protected` over `public` doesn't apply.

Use `private[this]` where performance really matters (since you'll get direct field access instead of methods this way). Otherwise, just settle on one style so people don't need to figure out why *this* property is `private` and *that* one is `private[this]`.

Comment: @om-nom-nom Actually, there isn't much to tell. JIT should inline the accessor method calls generated by `private` anyway, so the impact should be zero or at least very very small.

Comment: This answer is misleading, the actual reason is declaration-site variance (see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727849/445715).

Comment: @AndreyBreslav I disagree that this is _the_ reason. Yes, such a case exists but as the answer says it's quite rare.

Comment: Hmm. Marek Adamek's answer below seems to be the real reason to choose private[this] over private. The intent is to limit access to a specific instance, as opposed to all instances of the class.

Comment: @RamRajamony The question isn't asking what's the difference, it's asking which one should be preferred _when both can be used_.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - the question asks "Should I always use it by default?". I think you could improve your answer by saying that private[this] cannot be used if you need the field from another instance of the same class.

Comment: @Ram Rajamony perfectly sums up it here. And there is good example down below - https://stackoverflow.com/a/35911843/432903

Answer (score 144):

There is a case where `private[this]` is required to make code compile. This has to do with an interaction of variance notation and mutable variables. Consider the following (useless) class:

```
class Holder[+T] (initialValue: Option[T]) {
    // without [this] it will not compile
    private[this] var value = initialValue

    def getValue = value
    def makeEmpty { value = None }
}
```

So this class is designed to hold an optional value, return it as an option and enable the user to call `makeEmpty` to clear the value (hence the var). As stated, this is useless except to demonstrate the point.

If you try compiling this code with `private` instead of `private[this]` it will fail with the following error message:

> error: covariant type T occurs in contravariant position in type Option[T] of value value_=
>       class Holder[+T] (initialValue: Option[T]) {

This error occurs because value is a mutable variable on the covariant type T (+T) which is normally a problem unless marked as private to the instance with `private[this]`. The compiler has special handling in its variance checking to handle this special case.

So it's esoteric but there is a case where `private[this]` is required over `private`.

Comment: I can see why it fails when mutability is in the mix, but why do I [get the same error when nothing is mutable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29238887/3625)?

Comment: because _this answer is completely wrong_ . The actual reason is, as mentioned by Martin Odersky, the creator of Scala is.. this is another scope. **private [this]**, known as object private scope restricts the method to only to that object. therefore any other instance of the same class wont be able to access any **private [this]** members.

Answer (score 42):

`private var name` is accessible from any method of the `class Dummy` (and its companion `object Dummy`).

`private[this] var name` is accessible from methods of `this` object only, not from other objects of `class Dummy`.

Answer (score 19):

In most OOP programming language like java, private fields/methods mean that these private fields/methods are not accessible outside from the class. However, instances/objects of same class can have access to the private fields of objects using assignment operator or by means of copy constructor. In Scala,private[this] is object private,which makes sure that any other object of same class is unable to access private[this] members.

**Example**

1.Without private[this]

```
object ObjectPrivateDemo {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    var real = new User("realUserName", "realPassword")
    var guest = new User("dummyUserName", "dummyPassword")
    real.displayUser(guest)

  }
}

class User(val username:String,val password:String) {
  private var _username=username
  private var _password=password



  def displayUser(guest:User){

         println(" guest username="+guest._username+" guest password="+guest._password)
       guest._username= this._username
    guest._password=  this._password
       println(" guest username="+guest._username+" guest password="+guest._password)


  }
}
```

2.Using private[this]

```
class User(val username: String, val password: String) {
  private var _username = username
  private[this] var _password = password



  def displayUser(guest: User) {

    println(this._username)
    println(this._password)

    guest._username = this._username
    // for guest._password it will give this :error  value _password is not member of class User
    guest._password = this._password

  }
}
```

Hence private[this] makes sure that _password field is only accessible with this.

Comment: This is by far the clearest and more objective answer.

Answer (score 18):

> private[this] (equivalent to protected[this]) means that that "y" is
>   only visible to methods in the same instance. For example, you could
>   not reference y on a second instance in an equals method, i.e.,
>   "this.y == that.y" would generate a compilation error on "that.y".
>   [(source)](http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/scala-example-of-private-qualifier-td2002075.html)

so you can do private[this] every time you want but you can have some problem if you need refer it

Comment: `private[this]` is not equal to `protected[this]`. `protected[this]` allows subclass instances to access the member.

Comment: You can do `this.y == that.y` using neither private nor private[this], I just tried both

Answer (score 15):

This was tested using scala 2.11.5. Consider the code below

```
class C(private val x: Int) {
  override def equals(obj: Any) = obj match {
    case other: C => x == other.x
    case _ => false
  }
}

println(new C(5) == new C(5)) //true
println(new C(5) == new C(4)) //false
```

it will compile and work as this java (1.8) code

```
class C {
    private int x;

    public C(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof C) {
            return ((C) obj).x == x;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(new C(5).equals(new C(5))); //true
System.out.println(new C(5).equals(new C(4))); //false
```

however if you use '[this]' modifier the code below won't compile

```
class C(private[this] val x: Int) {
  override def equals(obj: Any) = obj match {
    case other: C => this.x == other.x //problem is here
    case _ => false
  }
}
```

This is because in the first case 'x' is accessible on class level, whereas in the second case is it more strict instance level. It means that 'x' can be accessed only from the instance to which it belongs. So 'this.x' is fine but 'other.x' is not.

You can refer to section 13.5 of "Programming in Scala: A Comprehensive Step-By-Step Guide" book for more details about access modifiers.

Comment: The question isn't asking what `private[this]` means. Note the first sentence.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. doesn't matter who considers it right or wrong. This is the explanation mentioned by creator of scala. it's called Object Private Scope.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on the performance issue Alexey Romanov has mentioned, here are some of my guesses.
Quotes from book "Programming in Scala: A Comprehensive Step-by-Step Guide, 2nd Edition" Section 18.2:

> In Scala, every var that is non-private member of some object implicitly defines a getter and a setter method with it.

To test it out, this code will cause compilation error:

```
class PrivateTest{
  var data: Int = 0
  def data_=(x : Int){
    require(x > 0)
    data = x
  }
}
```

Scala complains about `error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition`. Adding override keyword to `data_=` won't help should prove that the method is generated by the compiler. Adding `private` keyword to variable `data` will still cause this compilation error. However, the following code compiles fine:

```
class PrivateTest{
  private[this] var data: Int = 0
  def data_=(x : Int){
    require(x > 0)
    data = x
  }
}
```

So, I guess `private[this]` will prevent scala from generating getter and setter methods. Thus, accessing such variable will save the overhead of calling the getter and setter method.

Answer (score 2):

> Should I always use it by default? Or should I use it only in some
>   specific cases where I need to explicitly restrict changing field
>   value even for objects of the same class? In other words how should I
>   choose between

It's better to use `private[this]` if you plan to synchronize the variable.

Here a good example from the [scala style guide of the Spark team](https://github.com/databricks/scala-style-guide#private-fields):

```
// The following is still unsafe.
class Foo {
  private var count: Int = 0
  def inc(): Unit = synchronized { count += 1 }
}

// The following is safe.
class Foo {
  private[this] var count: Int = 0
  def inc(): Unit = synchronized { count += 1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

consider the notation of access_modifier[xxx], it indicates scope of it's target:

```scala
package demo.mxl

class PrivateThisDemo(private val aField: String, private[this] val bField: String) {
  def simpleStr: String = s"aField: $aField, bField: $bField"
}

object PrivateThisDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val obj = new PrivateThisDemo("a", "b")
    println(s"${obj.simpleStr}")
    println(s"${obj.aField}") // compile ok
    println(s"${obj.bField}") // compile error, because here out of 'this' scope
  }
}
```