# How can a private field be accessed from another object instance?

Tags: scala

I'm currently looking how covariant and contravariant type parametrization is handled in Scala. And there's a special case, where a var field must be private[this] in order to compile. From example in this code snippet (taken in this question: [private[this] vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private)):

```
class Holder[+T] (initialValue: Option[T]) {
    // without [this] it will not compile
    private[this] var value = initialValue

    def getValue = value
    def makeEmpty { value = None }
}
```

I understand this example. But what I can't understand, is in what case is a private field accessible from another instance than itselt (this)?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a member is plain-private, it is accessible from other instances of the same class. The `[this]` suffix makes it visible only to the instance that contains it.

Comment: Could you give me an example how an other instance of the same class accesses a plain-private member? I still don't get it...

Comment: They are common while implementing `equals`. Say you are to implement `equals` on your `Holder` class. One common approach is to do `def equals(that: Holder[T]) = (value == that.value)`. This code only compiles if `value` is made plain-private, because you are accessing `that.value` from the `this` instance (note that this is not the correct `Object.equals` signature, it is simplified for better understanding).