# private[this] in object definition

Tags: scala

I am wondering what it means to declare `private[this]` in an object definition? It makes sense to me in a class definition, but in object?

as in:

```
object Test {
  private[this] val t: Int = 5
}
```

what difference does it have compare to:

```
object Test {
  private val t: Int = 5
}
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private#9727849

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is significant when the object is a companion object of a class.  In that case the member that is declared `private[this]` may be accessed by the object but not instances of the corresponding class.