# Scala direct member access

Tags: scala, compilation, jvm

This is a question about how Scala is compiled.  Is there a way to get the compiled code to refer directly to var members (getfield, putfield) rather than going through accessor functions (invokespecial, `_$eq$`)?

I thought making the var final would do it, but no.  Here's an example:

```
class foo {
  private final var x: Int = 0

  def incr { x += 1 }
  def result: Int = x
}
```

and here is the output from javap:

```
Compiled from "foo.scala"
public class foo {
  private int x;

  private final int x();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #13                 // Field x:I
       4: ireturn

  private final void x_$eq(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: iload_1
       2: putfield      #13                 // Field x:I
       5: return

  public void incr();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: aload_0
       2: invokespecial #22                 // Method x:()I
       5: iconst_1
       6: iadd
       7: invokespecial #24                 // Method x_$eq:(I)V
      10: return
...
```

Or should I not care about this because the JVM will inline the accessors and the performance will be the same?

Here's the equivalent Java code:

```
class bar {
    private int x;

    void incr() { x += 1; }
    int result() { return x; }
}
```

and bytecode:

```
final class bar {
  private int x;

  void incr();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: dup
       2: getfield      #2                  // Field x:I
       5: iconst_1
       6: iadd
       7: putfield      #2                  // Field x:I
      10: return

  ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `private[this]` [ref](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/packages-and-imports.html) :

> ...
>
> A private[C] where C is the outermost enclosing class is the same as
>   just private in Java.
>
> Finally, Scala also has an access modifier that is even more restrictive than private. A definition labeled private[this] is accessible only from within the same object that contains the definition. Such a definition is called object-private.
>
> ...

```
class foo {                                                                                                                                             
  private[this] final var x: Int = 0

  def incr { x += 1 }
  def result: Int = x
}
```

You get

```
Compiled from "foo.scala"
public class foo {
  private int x;
  public void incr();
  public int result();
  public foo();
}
```

Note this usually leads to uglier code (imho), so if this kind of performance gain doesn't really matter, you should avoid it.

[private[this] vs private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and references.  I don't get accessors with `private[this]` but I do with `private[foo]`.  I guess `private[foo]` is the same as `private` in Java in terms of accessibility.

Comment: Updated the answer with the text from the reference that says what you observed. :)

Answer (score 1):

-- Or should I not care about this because the JVM will inline the accessors and the performance will be the same?

Yes, exactly.

Comment: although it might exhaust the max inlining depth faster