# Scala: what is the difference between "private class" and "private[this] class" for top level classes?

Tags: scala

I know what `private[this]` means in the context of a method or class variable, but what does it mean in the context of a top level class? Is it the same as `private[package]`, where the `this` keyword substitutes the name of the current package?

Comment: Yes,
Check this for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698677/privatethis-vs-private

Comment: I saw it, but unless I'm missing something, there's no mention of the semantics for top level classes. There is no "instance" to be private to in this case (unless the package is an instance, but I've never known packages to be first level objects in Scala).

Comment: Ha! I thought that it might have to do with the synthetic object that wraps interpreted scripts, but indeed, the program `private[this] class PrivateThis` compiles with `scalac`, not just as a script. That's funny.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Stock{
 private var price: Double
 def isHigh(that: Stock): Boolean =  this.price > that.price
}
```

here that is outside object accessing private price variable But if we define

```
private[this] var price: Double
```

like this then that cant access price

Comment: I asked about `private[this]` classes, not class members.