# Scala syntax like private[this]

Tags: scala, terminology

I am new to scala, could anyone pinpoints what kind of terminology for the below square bracket **[this]** ?

`private[this] lazy val outputAttributes = AttributeSeq(output)`

Thank you.

Comment: See this as a usage example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43644925/1809978

Answer (score 5):

This is called [object-private access modifier](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#private)

> Members marked `private` without a qualifier are called class-private,
>   whereas members labeled with `private[this]` are called object-private.

and specifies the [most restrictive access](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-control-scala-method-scope-object-private-package#solution-scala-access-modifiers-scopes)

> The most restrictive access is to mark a method
>   as “object-private.” When you do this, the method is available only to
>   the current instance of the current object. Other instances of the
>   same class cannot access the method.

More precisely, `[this]` part of `private[this]` is referred to as access *qualifier*:

```
AccessModifier    ::=  (‘private’ | ‘protected’) [AccessQualifier]
AccessQualifier   ::=  ‘[’ (id | ‘this’) ‘]’
```

Answer (score 1):

`private[this]` takes the privacy to one step further and it makes the field object `private`. Unlike `private`, now the field cannot be accessed by other instances of the same type, making it more private than plain private setting.

For example,

```
class Person {
 private val name = "John"
 def show(p: Person) = p.name
}

(new Person).show(new Person) // result: John

class Person {
 private[this] val name = "John"
 def show(p: Person) = p.name // compilation error
}
```

After adding private[this], field can only be accessed by current instance not any other instance of class.